# How to make this table design in angular with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I data in this format in my angular controller. These are dummy datas and will be fetched from some sort of services later.

```
$scope.attendanceLog =
    {
      attendances:
      [
          {
              date:'12.12.17',
              entries:
              [
                  {
                      time:'12PM',
                      device:'1212',
                      location:'katabon'
                  },
                  {
                      time:'1PM',
                      device:'1212',
                      location:'katabon'
                  },
                  {
                      time:'2PM',
                      device:'1321',
                      location:'katabon'
                  }
              ]

          },
          {
              date:'13.12.17',
              entries:
                  [
                      {
                          time:'12PM',
                          device:'1212',
                          location:'katabon'
                      },
                      {
                          time:'1PM',
                          device:'1212',
                          location:'katabon'
                      },
                      {
                          time:'2PM',
                          device:'1321',
                          location:'katabon'
                      },
                      {
                          time:'5PM',
                          device:'1321',
                          location:'katabon'
                      }
                  ]
          }
      ]
    };
```

Now I designed the table to view this data like this. Here is the html code
for the table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th class="text-center">Time</th>
    <th class="text-center">Device</th>
    <th class="text-center">Location</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="attendance in attendanceLog.attendances">
    <td rowspan="{{attendance.entries.length}}" class="date">{{attendance.date}}</td>
    <td>{{attendance.entries[0].time}}</td>
    <td>{{attendance.entries[0].device}}</td>
    <td>{{attendance.entries[0].location}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="entries in attendance.entries" ng-if="$index>0">
    <td>{{entries.time}}</td>
    <td>{{entries.device}}</td>
    <td>{{entries.location}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to make every other instance of the highlighted sections' background a diffrent color.[Here is the reference image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lemqP.png)
So if there are 5 dates then the 1st, 3rd and 5th date cell and all the other cells on their right side would have a different color.

Now is there any way to do this with angular. I am sorry if its a stupid question. I am new to front end development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing new rows in the table I created a new table for every date. And then I applied the css class on every odd numbered table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="...." class =
  ng-class ="$index % 2 == 0 ? 'table table-bordered striped':'table table-bordered'" >
   .......
   .......
</table>
```

Here striped is the class I used to highlight the odd numbered records background a different color

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to have one expression for the table entries and use ng-class-odd and ng-class-even:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="..."
    ng-class-odd="'someOddClass'" ng-class-even="'someEvenClass'">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you'd just need to change your styling.

Comment: Props for the ng-class-even and odd suggestion. Any suggestions on how I can replace the two ng-repeats with a single one